# Laravel Query Multiple Conditions

Tags: laravel

```
 public function queryCountUsers($query) {
        $query->where(['confirmed' => true])->count();
    }
```

I want to query all the users who are already confirmed and those all users who have role_id of 2 or 3 but How can i do it ?

Answer (score 1):

You could add `->where('role_id',2)->orWhere('role_id',3)` to your function, but it's probably a better idea to use Laravel's [`whereIn`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries) function:

```
$query->where(['confirmed' => true])->whereIn('role_id', [2,3])->count();
```

This is supported in every version of Laravel.